# Combine (summarize) certain rows based on a category

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble, summarize

I'm working with a simple dataframe in R, similar to this one:

```
data <- data.frame(
  "food"= c("Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Meat", "Fish", "Cherries", "Wheat"),
  "kg"= c(2,3,1,2,6,4,5)
)
```

My point is that I would like to create a new row, called "Fruits" and having the kg value of "Banana", "Orange", "Apple" and "Cherries" combined (I would then delete those and just keep "Fruits").

The closer I've come to a solution has been this attempt:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data %>% 
  add_row(.data = data.frame(food="Fruits",
                             total=sum(data$kg[c=1,2,3,6])))

# Error message: 'incorrect number of dimensions'
```

I am quite new at R, so I don't know how to create a value that stores the addition of the rows I wanted and include it in a new row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say we have 2 categories (Fruits and Protein), while "Wheat" is not in either groups, hence, won't be "summarized" (if you only want "Fruits" to be summarized, you simply drop the `Protein` from `categories` list).

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

categories <- list(Fruits = c("Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Cherries"), 
                   Protein = c("Meat", "Fish"))

enframe(categories) %>% 
  unnest(value) %>% 
  full_join(data, .,  join_by(food == value)) %>% 
  mutate(name = coalesce(name, food)) %>% 
  summarise(food = first(name), kg = sum(kg, na.rm = T), .by = name) %>% 
  select(-name)

#>      food kg
#> 1  Fruits 10
#> 2 Protein  8
#> 3   Wheat  5
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for answering: is there something that I can do so that your output doesn't lead to `Error in quickdf(.data[names(cols)]) : length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE` ? I don't quite understand what it means.

Comment: @RebecaOdC As you can see, it works for the dataset that you provided above. Would you be able to share a sample dataset that would reproduce that error? You could read this post https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406 about reproducible examples. Then, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78149202/edit) your question and share the example dataset there.

Comment: You are right! My bad, I made a mistake when reproducing your code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  "food"= c("Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Meat", "Fish", "Cherries", "Wheat"),
  "kg"= c(2,3,1,2,6,4,5)
)

data %>% 
   mutate(type = case_when(food %in% c("Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Cherries") ~ "Fruits",
                           TRUE ~ "Other")) %>%
   group_by(type) %>%
   summarize(total_kg = sum(kg),
            .groups = "keep") %>%
   ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 × 2
#  type   total_kg
#  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Fruits       10
#2 Other        13
```

Here you create an additional variable called `type` that specifies the type of food. You use the `type` variable to group your data and then you can sum the `kg` column by group. `summarize()` collapses the dataset into one row per value in the `type` variable.

If you want to keep the `food` variable, you can use this `mutate()` instead of `summarize()`. To only keep the total kgs by group, use the second code chunk here (the one with `distinct()`):

```r
data %>% 
   mutate(type = case_when(food %in% c("Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Cherries") ~ "Fruits",
                              TRUE ~ "Other")) %>%
   group_by(type) %>%
   mutate(total_kg = sum(kg)) %>%
   ungroup() 

# A tibble: 7 × 4
#  food        kg type   total_kg
#  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Banana       2 Fruits       10
#2 Orange       3 Fruits       10
#3 Apple        1 Fruits       10
#4 Meat         2 Other        13
#5 Fish         6 Other        13
#6 Cherries     4 Fruits       10
#7 Wheat        5 Other        13

data1 %>%
   filter(type == "Fruits") %>%
   distinct(type, total_kg)  

# A tibble: 1 × 2
#  type   total_kg
#  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Fruits       10
```

Comment: Thank you for answering: is there something I can do so that the first part of your code doesn't output a one-row table of `# total_kg  .groups # 23   keep` ? I can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: @RebecaOdC When I run the first part of the code exactly as written above, I get a table with two rows and two columns. The first column is `type` and has "Fruits" and "Other". The second column is `total_kg` and has a 10 (for Fruits) and 13 (for Other). Are you running it exactly as written?